# How to retrieve the IDs of existing custom managed content types

Tags: soql, tooling-api, workbench, content

I have followed [these steps](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/11/use-the-cms-app-to-create-content.html) to create some custom managed content types for my organization.  It seems like the delete request needs an ID of the record to be deleted via the tooling API, which makes sense.  However, the `managedContentType` metadata type doesn't support being queried with SOQL.  My question is, how do I retrieve the IDs of the existing `managedContentType` records in the system so I can delete previous versions that should no longer be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get ManagedContentType Id From workbench.

1. go to: Info > Metadata Types & Components
2. choose "ManagedContentType" from the dropdown list

All ManagedContentTypes components will be displayed under "Components".

3.Select your specific ManagedContentType to get it's Id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT Id, ContentKey FROM ManagedContent
```